# Is there a way or a tool to detect and list all WCF end points hosted in a server ?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a very annoying situation. My server is polluted with many WCF services. Some are hosted in IIS, some in windows services, some in console processes!!! The files for these services are scattered across different locations in the machine and I thought perhaps, I could do a file search for all endpoints. But then later realized, there are also some services which are just hosted with code (binding, endpoints etc.. done in code).

I am in to a re-engineering task on the code base and wondering if there is a tool or some utility which if I run from my server can detect all open WCF end points ?

Much Thanks.

Comment: Look at the WCF statistics (counters) in Perfmon. I don't recall if every single connection point gets listed but I think it might.

Comment: Do you have access to the server (ie. can you remote into it?) Or are you trying to get this information externally?

Comment: @Justin - Yes, I can remote to the server and have admin rights as well if that would help.

Comment: @500 - I tried that as well without success. Not sure if we could see the connection end point urls this way.